# Finding Best fit line of white pixels

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, edge-detection

I want to find the best fit line of the grass edge (see desired output).

I am using OPENCV currently.

```
    import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

image_org = cv2.imread("grass pic.jpg")
image = np.copy(image_org)

HSV = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

cv2.imshow("hsv", HSV)

low = np.array([23, 98, 0])
high = np.array([253, 255, 255])

mask = cv2.inRange(HSV, low, high)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
canny = cv2.Canny(mask,50,150)
cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\Main\Documents\Work\Projects\Lawnmower - AI/grassedge.jpg', canny)
cv2.imshow("result", canny)
```

Starting from:
[image]

I obtained Current Output:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: "the best fit line" -- what you show as desired output is not a line (it's not straight)...

Comment: try curve approximation: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c

Comment: @DanMašek: better say it is a line, not a straight line.

Comment: You'd better apply strong smoothing to the image to remove the zigzags before edge detection. You can also convert to hue or saturation and binarize to get a continuous outline.